# What is the highest frequency for ripples on water

Tags: waves, surface-tension, vibrations

I want to transmit sound vibrations as ripples on water, as an experimental audio delay effect. Can I make ripples at audio frequencies, that will travel over about 10cm or more?

How about other liquids like mercury? Mercury would have a higher inertia so air friction losses would be less.

Comment: You can make ultrasonic ripples, if you like. I wouldn't recommend using mercury. It is poisonous and not just a little. Whatever advantage you expect from it is not worth the exposure or the (monetary) cost to safely avoid it.

Comment: In the past a standard way of introducing a delay was to use sound waves passing through glass.  However the speed of sound in glass might be to high for your application? http://www.extra.research.philips.com/hera/people/aarts/_Philips%20Bound%20Archive/PTechReview/PTechReview-29-1968-243.pdf

Comment: @CuriousOne You definitely mean ultrasonic ripples on the surface, not just ultrasonic waves traveling through the water? Ripples on the surface travel much slower so it would be possible to make an audible delay in a small area.

Comment: @NickCollier: Yes, one can make ultrasonic ripples on the surface, they will just be very small. Farcher is correct that SAW (surface acoustic wave) filters and delay lines on glass and piezo-ceramics are more common than the use of liquids. It's not clear to my why you would want to do this... practical delays for these frequencies are best implemented digitally, no analog technology will ever come even close to what can be done by digitizing.

Comment: It is mainly for a demonstration video to put on my website. Also I think there will be a lot of complex artefacts doing this way, I don't want a clean delay, that would sound pretty boring. Perhaps I should have said reverberation effect.